# Resize DIV proportionally in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

I have an online magazine design, which shows each page of the magazine in a carousel.
The problem I have is that i want to make sure that the page is visible regardless of how a user resizes their browser.

I currently have the CSS as:
width:100%; height: auto; but the problem with this is that the height goes beyond the height of the viewport as the browser gets wider.
I want to make sure it's always visible - whether the viewport is landscape or portrait.

I'm assuming I need a touch of JS or Jquery perhaps, but this is something I have no idea how to do.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Andy

Comment: make the fiddle or provide the screen shot pls

Answer (score 0):

```
function ResizeContent() {
   $('MyElement').css('height', $(window).outerHeight() + 'px');
   // or
   $('MyElement').outerHeight($(window).outerHeight());
}

$(window).resize(function () {
   ResizeContent();
});
ResizeContent();
```

Should do the trick...

UPDATE:

```
function ResizeContent() {
       $('MyElement').css('max-height', $(window).outerHeight() + 'px');
       $('MyElement').css('max-width', $(window).outerWidth() + 'px');
}
```

[A Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jabark/4e3CW/)

Comment: Thanks for this - but it doesn't seem to resize proportionally - it just resizes to the full visible viewport.

Comment: Updated my answer based on this new information. The reason it would no be proportional is because you still have the `width:100%;` I'm guessing?

Comment: Ok. But what do I set my width to though?

Comment: Did you actually look at the JSFiddle example?

Comment: I did yes - but this has a fixed pixel width - Maybe I didn't explain my problem, but I need the div and it's contents to scale proportionally when the browser is resized.

Comment: What you're saying makes no sense. "This has a fixed pixel width" and `width: 100%;` don't really go together I'm afraid ;). my suggestion means that it will not overflow the boundaries of the browser window, no matter how big it is. If you look at my [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jabark/4e3CW/) and change the height and widths of the "#window" element, you can see what will happen in each circumstance. If you add `display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;` to the window, it will also centre it vertically :)

Comment: Thanks for this - but what I mean is your Fiddle has a Fixed pixel width - so is only resized manually in the css. What I need is for the image to resize proportionally when the browser window is resized - does that make more sense?